# R triangular numbers function

Tags: r, statistics, triangular

While working on a small program for calculating the right triangular number that fulfils an equation, I stumbled over a page that holds documentation on the function Triangular()
[Triangular function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Zseq/versions/0.2.0/topics/Triangular)

When I tried to use this, Rstudio says it couldn't find it and I can't seem to find any other information about what library this could be in.

Does this function even exist and/or are there other ways to fill a vector with triangular numbers?

Comment: did you load the package `Zseq`?

Comment: No, I couldn't find which package it was in. Thank you!

Comment: `f=function(n) n*(n+1)/2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Here is a base R solution to define your custom triangular number generator, i.e.,

```
myTriangular <- function(n) choose(seq(n),2)
```

or

```
myTriangular <- function(n) cumsum(seq(n)-1)
```

such that

```
> myTriangular(10)
 [1]  0  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45
```

- If you would like to use `Triangular()` from package `Zseq`, then please try

```
Zseq::Triangular(10)
```

such that

```
> Zseq::Triangular(10)
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 10:
 [1] 0  1  3  6  10 15 21 28 36 45
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem perfectly! Is there a performance difference between the two solutions?

Comment: @Esye I did not compared their performance in terms of speed...but `Zseq::Triangular` seems able to deal with super large numbers, which might be tough for the base R solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to do it yourself:

```r
triangular <- function(n) sapply(1:n, function(x) sum(1:x))
```

So you can do:

```
triangular(10)
# [1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```